# Can I use a C Variable Length Array in C++03 and C++11?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, gcc, variable-length-array

C has a really cool feature called variable length arrays. Its available in C90 and above, and it allows deferring the size of the array until runtime. See GCC's manual [6.19 Arrays of Variable Length](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

I'm working in C++. At `std=c++11`, I'm catching a compile failure due to the use of `alloca` under Cygwin. I want to switch to variable length arrays, if possible. I also want to try and avoid `std::vector` and `std::array` because I want to stay out of the memory manager. I believe every little bit helps, so I'm happy to take these opportunities (that some folks consider peepholes).

Can I use a variable length array in C++03 and C++11?

Comment: You can achieve VLA by using alloca

Comment: Would it be a problem to put some sanity bounds on your program and use a static-sized array?

Comment: Its not the bounds checking that bothers me. Its going into the memory manager time and time again each time this particular function is invoked..... Since I can't depend on dynamic arrays (thanks Basile), I'll have to consider a switch to a `std::array` since this is C++ 11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s are not in standard C++03 or C++11, so you'll better avoid them if you want to write strictly standard conforming code (and use e.g. `std::vector`, which generally use heap for its data - but you might use your own allocator...).

However, several C++ compilers (recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) & [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)) are accepting VLAs as an extension.

It is the same for [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member); they are not standard in C++ (only in C) but some compilers accept them.

[dynarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray)-s did not get into the C++11 standard...

Comment: Thanks Basile. I was kind of worried about that. I'm glad I asked. And thanks for the answer.

Comment: I followed your link to [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) and don't understand what's to special about them. Aren't they the same as `struct {unsigned length; double*array; };`, i.e. `double*array` instead of `double array[]`?

Comment: @Walter: No, pointers are not arrays. When allocating a pointer to a `struct` ended by a flexible array member, you will usually allocate some extra space for that flexible array member.

Answer (score 2):

Not if you want code that is standard C++.

No C++ standard supports VLAs, but some C++ compilers do as a vendor-specific extension.

You can achieve a similar effect in C++ using the standard `vector`.    Note that, unlike VLAs which can only be sized when created, a standard `vector` can be resized as needed  (subject to performing appropriate operations on it).