# Set size of char[] via int variable

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I've done quite a bit of research on how to set an arrays size using a variable of datatype `int`, but haven't been able to find anything of use.

So here is an example of what I've tried in which gives me an error saying `"expression must have a const value"`

```
char * charptr = "test";
int sze = strlen(charptr);
char str[sze];
```

Sorry if this question is idiotic, I'm still quite new to `c++`

Any help will be appreciated though!

Comment: An excellent choice would be to use `std.:string` instead of a `char` array.

Comment: If you are new to C++, you should not use pointers. Pointers are a low-level expert tool, mainly for optimizing implementations and for low-level operations, and they should not be necessary to just get something working.

Comment: You can't do that in standard C++, but some C++ compilers have extensions that let you do it. Given that we have the C++ standard containers, it's not a very interesting feature.

Comment: @KerrekSB I am not writing my c++ 'program' on windows or anything like that, string.h is unavailable to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use a C Variable Length Array in C++03 and C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645309/can-i-use-a-c-variable-length-array-in-c03-and-c11)

Comment: @C0d1ng: What has `string.h` to do with anything? That header is deprecated in C++ anyway.

Comment: @KerrekSB lol, i am unable to use the string struct (string.h) unless i were to re-create it. So in my case i need to use char* or char[]

Comment: @C0d1ng: You're thinking of a completely different header, `<string>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB ok? I meant the same thing, i never use it nor need it so easy to mix up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sze` is not known at *compile-time*; C++ does **not** support *variable length arrays* so `char str[sze];` is not valid C++.

One workaround would be to use `char* str = new char[sze];` but this can cause you problems since you *must* balance this with a subsequent `delete[] str;` else you'll leak memory.

It's far better to use the built-in string class `std::string` if you can.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use dynamic allocation.

```
int size = 1337;
char *str = new char[size];
```

By doing this, the program will allocate memory on the heap during runtime.

You cannot do `char str[size]` because `size` is not known at compile time and then the compiler does not know how much space it has to allocate on the stack.

Of course remember to do `delete [] str` after its usage.